# Interactive GoT map with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, interactive

I'm trying to create an interactive Game of Thrones map for a project. I have a working map, kind of.

What I want to do is when I click a certain area in the map, it'll open up a different image, with different clickable areas like houses and such.

This is what the map looks like so far:

[image]

When I click a red square, I want to open up a new similar image, with just that specific region. Could this be done by adding a button on top of the image and when I click that, it'll call a class that will replace the image and stuff? I don't know how to get a button on top of the image, after trying and searching how to do it.

Any advise would be appreciated. I am quite new to programming.

Here is the code I have so far;

```
   import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MapDemo extends Application {




public void start (Stage ps) {

ImageView img=new ImageView(getClass().getResource("map.jpg").toExternalForm());

List<County> alltowns = new ArrayList<County>();

alltowns.add(new County("The North",165,265));
alltowns.add(new County("The Vale",265,415));
alltowns.add(new County("Crownlands",280,520));
alltowns.add(new County("Stormlands",280,635));
alltowns.add(new County("Dorne",190,725));
alltowns.add(new County("The Reach",150,600));
alltowns.add(new County("Westerland",135,505));
alltowns.add(new County("Riverlands",180,440));
alltowns.add(new County("Iron Isles",80,400));









img.setOnMouseMoved(e->{
    ps.setTitle(e.getX()+", "+e.getY());
});


img.setOnMousePressed(e->{
    for(County t : alltowns)
    {
        double dist=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(t.getX()-e.getX(),2)+Math.pow(t.getY()-e.getY(),2));

        if(dist<=20)
            System.out.println(t.getName());
    }
});


ps.setScene(new Scene(new Group(img),413,796));
ps.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}

//---------------------------------------------

class County {
    String name;
    double x,y;

    public County(String n, double a, double b){
        name=n;
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;

    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the source of the image is in SVG I would assign ids to the shapes of the various regions in a SVG drawing application (e.g. inkscape). With tools like SVG2FXML¹ you can easily load it with the FXMLLoader². Either add the onClick methods by editing the source in a simple editor, or search the loaded node tree for the ids and attach the handlers programatically.

This way you avoid the need for the red square buttons and you make the whole region react to the user's input.

¹ https://github.com/grmartin/SVG2FXML-Extended

² I don't know if the converter is capable of converting *all* SVGs to a corresponding FXML.